Inject Javascript on a webpage in only parent/main window
I need to showcase a demo of a feature to my product manager. Demo works on an external website (one of our customers) because of some configurations on that website.
I am using Requestly Chrome Extension to Inject my company’s javascript on this website.
It always works fine but this time I have noticed it is injecting multiple times on the page which is breaking the demo.
After some research, I found that it is happening because this website has many Iframes (because of Ads) and Requestly is also injecting the scripts in the ad containers/windows.
Is it possible to inject the javascript only in the parent window using Requestly?

There is no such feature as of now, but you can enclose your JS code around if(window.top===window.self){} for this. But it won't work for files. You can track this issue for further updates.

Thanks, this can solve part of the problems. In case of custom scripts it solves the problem. I'm hoping Requestly will add support for files as well.
